# how i can get the property value for "ShowInNewForm" for a site column

Tags: 2013, development, powershell

I want to know if a field is set to be shown in new form or not. so i run this power-shell script:-

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $web = Get-SPWeb http://****/order/
PS C:\Windows\system32> $field = $web.Fields["Live Order"]
PS C:\Windows\system32> Write-Host  $field.ShowInNewForm
```

but i did not get any result..

Comment: Does the information help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SPField.ShowInNewForm is **nullable** property and is used to get or set a Boolean value that specify whether the field is displayed in the form that is used to create list items.

By default, the field will display in the form and the value is `null`.

You can output the `$field` and you will find the `ShowInNewForm` value.

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
$web = Get-SPWeb http://****/order/
$field = $web.Fields["Live Order"]
$field
```

[image]

If the value is `null`, it also means that the field is displayed in the form.

Learn more about:

[SPField properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ms469531(v%3Doffice.15))

[SPField.ShowInNewForm property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ms437330%28v%3Doffice.15%29)